# OpenXR implementation for ARCore

Tags: arcore, openxr

I'm currently teaching AR and VR in France and I see that ARCore does not implement OpenXR nor does it provide extensions for it.

It would be very appreciated if ARCore implemented OpenXR so engines such as Godot would have the opportunity to integrated AR features for smartphones.

Thanks a lot !